# Manage SDK License Key in netCore

Tags: c#, security, .net-core, secret-key

I purchased a SDK from a third party. They developer license also grants the rights to distribute applications, no separate runtime licenses needed.

I got a license key (simple string), and need to apply the license in the source code like this

```
sdkApplication.ActivateLicense(LicenseFeature.Client, "XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX");
```

What is the best way to manage the license key? Obviously I cannot just paste it in the sourcecode, otherwise it would end up in the git. I could put it in a json file, but this would be read at runtime and I would have to deploy the licens key in cleartext with the application.

So, how can I manage the key in such a way that it isn't in the sourcecode, but gets read at compile-time so I do not have to distribut it with the application?

Comment: If it's compiled into the application, and you're handing that application to other people, it can be decompiled back out. The only way to keep secrets secret is to keep them on machines that only you control. Put another way, are you going to singlehandedly solve a problem that the games/movie industries couldn't in relation to piracy?

Comment: I know it can be decompiled. But this would at least be somewhat harder, and as long as the user does not know that this SDK is used (it handles internal things, not obvious from the outside) he might not even look. Putting the key in a json file next to the executable is really serving it on a golden plate. And providing the App only as native code and maybe using some kind of obfuscator would additionally make it somewhat harder. But for this, the key needs to be in the executable.So yeah, of course a dedicated cracker always gets the key. But someone just lookign for an easy catch is out.